# php include_once and get method

Tags: php

I have one `board.php` file that displays a board on my web page. This file includes once a `boardEngine.php` file which has every variables and matrix initialized, plus every function needed for computing.

I put a form in my `board.php` so that I can enter my next move on the board. `board.php` code goes like this:

```
<!doctype html>
  <html> 
<body>
<?php   
 include_once('boardEngine.php');
?>

 <div id='board'>


<?php
 if (isset($_GET['move'] ))  {
  checkMove($_POST['queryMove']); // checkMove is from boardEngine.php 
 }
  printBoard();  // function from boardEngine.php 

 ?>
 </div>

 <form id="moveForm" action="board.php?move" method="post" >

  <input type="text" name="queryMove" placeholder="form: 'e2f3' (e2 to f3)" required> </p>
  <input type="submit" value=">move!<" >


 </form>
</body>
```

The problem is that when I submit the move, `board.php` is reloaded with a set `$_GET['move']`. Since it is reloaded, it seems like `boardEngine.php` gets included again, and every positions in the matrix are initialized.

As I understand the thing so far, the move is submitted, `board.php` is reloaded, `boardEngine.php` is included another time with every position being reset, then because the `$_GET['move']` variable has been set through the form, one move will be computed. Once a new move is submitted, the board will be reset and the last move will be considered, and so on.

Am I wrong? How can I solve this problem?

Edit 1: Here is the look of my boardEngine.php code:

```
 <?php

define("PAWN", 10);
define("KNIGHT", 20);
define("BISHOP", 30);
define("ROOK", 40);
define("QUEEN", 50);
define("KING", 100);
define("B_PAWN", -10);
define("B_KNIGHT", -20);
define("B_BISHOP", -30);
define("B_ROOK", -40);
define("B_QUEEN", -50);
define("B_KING", -100);

$board = array( 
    array("", 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h'),
array( 1, B_ROOK, B_KNIGHT, B_BISHOP, B_QUEEN, B_KING, B_BISHOP, B_KNIGHT, B_ROOK),
array(2, B_PAWN, B_PAWN, B_PAWN, B_PAWN, B_PAWN, B_PAWN, B_PAWN, B_PAWN),
array(3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
array(4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
array(5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
array(6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
array(7, PAWN, PAWN, PAWN, PAWN, PAWN, PAWN, PAWN, PAWN),
array(8, ROOK, KNIGHT, BISHOP, QUEEN, KING, BISHOP, KNIGHT, ROOK)

         );


function checkMove($query) {

 global $board;

 if(strlen($query) != 4) {
  return "Wrong query!";
 }
//...
// Next modfy the $board positions according to rules


}

function printBoard() {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: btw. why do you need an extra $_GET parameter? is ìf (isset($_POST['queryMove']))` not good enough?

Comment: Every time you load a PHP script, it starts fresh. All variables are reset, include files are reloaded, etc. The only thing that persists between runs are session variables.

Comment: bwoebi: the post method is fairly enough but doesn't solve my problem

Comment: barmar: yeah I want to solve that problem so I can get a web site working only with php. THen I will make it with javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http is a stateless protocol, which means that the script will run all over again for each request. And posting a form creates a new request.

You're gonna have to persist your game's state somehow. `$_SESSION` is a good idea, as Barmar suggested too.

**EDIT**: Since you posted your board engine, and just to get started, do the following:

1) Add a `session_start();` at the beginning of your code

2) Replace the `$board=....` part with `

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['board']))
  $_SESSION['board']=.......
```

3) Replace every occurence of `$board` in your code with `$_SESSION['board']`

Comment: THanks I am new to php and thought php files would not be loaded each times because of the include_once(). Using $_SESSION works perfectly :)

Answer (score 1):

How does `BoardEngine.php` look?

Why not make it a Class? Something like this:

```
class BoardEngine {

//You can remove the construct function below, if you don't need it
function __construct(argument)
{
    //Constructor code here if needed
}

public function printBoard()
{
    # function code here...
}
public function checkMove($var)
{
    # function code here...
}
public function yetanotherone()
{
    # function code here...
}
```

}

You can then put all your "engine" logic in there.

And in your `board.php`:

```
<?php   
require_once('BoardEngine.php');

$boardEngine = New BoardEngine();

if (isset($_GET['move'] ))  {
    $boardEngine->checkMove($_POST['queryMove']); // checkMove is from boardEngine.php 
}
    $boardEngine->printBoard();  // function from boardEngine.php 
?>

<div id='board'>

</div>

<form id="moveForm" action="board.php?move" method="post" >

<input type="text" name="queryMove" placeholder="form: 'e2f3' (e2 to f3)" required> </p>
<input type="submit" value=">move!<" >


</form>
</body>
```

To save moves on each reload, I would also suggest using `$_SESSION`. 
Or in your `BoardEngine` class:

```
private $lastmove;

public function setLastMove($value)
{
    $this->lastmove = $value;
}
public function getLastMove($value)
{
    return $this->lastmove;
}
```

Now in your board.php you can set the last move with:

```
$boardEngine->setLastmove($var);
```

get it last move with:

```
$boardEngine->getLastmove();
```

EDIT: To clerify:
To save last move as a `$_SESSION` and echo it out:

```
$_SESSION['lastmove'] = $boardEngine->getLastmove();
echo $_SESSION['lastmove'];
```

Comment: The thing is, 'action="board.php?move" ' will reload my page, and thus require boardEngine.php again and creating a boardEngine class anew, will it not?
What can I do with $_SESSION? Saving the board position in it?

Comment: It will only instatiate the class. I updated my post how you could use the class to remember last move.

Comment: To use $_SESSION simply put $_SESSION = $yourvalue;
Or if you need more $_SESSION variables, use it like so:
$_SESSION['one'] = "one";
$_SESSION['two'] = "two"; 
And so on

Comment: @Bolli: Nice and tidy (I personally _love_ OOP) but, alas, irrelevant. Doing it OOP-style doesn't persist anything.

Comment: @geomagas True true - but this way he could store the lastmove and use it again. I'm not gonna write the entire game though :)
$_SESSION would be the way to go. I'm not expert on OOP (yet), I'm still learning.

Comment: Thanks Bolli my comment on geomagas' post applies here too. I did plan to make classes for javascript, because I think it will be more useful there

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, don't say

`board.php?move` in the action. It is better to specify get variables with values.
Change it to `board.php?move=yes`

Then,

```
if(isset($_GET['move'])) if($_GET['move']==="yes")  include_once('boardEngine.php');
```